# Connection state and error metadata best practice with Rx

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, signalr, system.reactive

### System

I'm building a server-side streaming calculation engine to perform live calculations on ticking market data for a financial services firm.

The idea is that the calculation server obtains connections to various market data sources (mostly Bloomberg) and recalculates various relatively complex calculations whenever new inputs (prices, FX rates, etc) arrive.

Those calculation results will then get pushed to the various clients (WPF desktop) connected to the server using SignalR.  On both the client and the server, I'll be using Rx and IObservable to implement a pipeline for the calculations and cascading downstream activity from them.

### Problem

The thing is, a valid state for the calculations might be 0.3995, but it might be "Waiting for price" or even "Server down".

I don't want to use the built-in Rx error system, as it seems brittle.  As soon as any exception is encountered, an IObservable terminates forever and must be re-subscribed to be recovered.  I would like my streams to be robust and persistent and for the expected possible recoverable error states to be pieces of data rather than exceptions.

### My Current Thought

I'm toying with wrapping the return data in the stream in a sort of monad, something like this:

**Does anyone have any better suggestions?  Or some pointers that would help me correctly frame the problem?**

```
    public enum TransientState 
    {
        NotReady = 0,
        Ok = 1,
        Faulted = 2,
        Fatal = 3
    }

    public struct RxMessage<T> 
    {
        public TransientState State { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimestampUtc { get; set; }
        public string Fault { get; set; }
        public T Payload { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I build such system before with RX, the way I handle my exceptions was by wrapping them Polly https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly, allowing flexible configuration while the app in production. As far as I remember that approach resulted in a stable system. Assuming that network connections fail I had to validate the data from the time the connection dropped.

Comment: Nice, thank you.  I'd not encountered Polly before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach makes sense, and certainly would work.

I would probably prefer a separate status stream. With a separate stream, you're not continuing to push the same status data and clients can separate handling of new data and changes in status.

For example:

```
var statusStream = new Subject<TransientState>();
var tickStream = new Subject<float>();

var finalStream = statusStream
    .Select(s => s == TransientState.Ok ? tickStream : Observable.Never<float>() )
    .Switch();

finalStream.Dump(); //linqpad

statusStream.OnNext(TransientState.NotReady);
tickStream.OnNext(0);
statusStream.OnNext(TransientState.Ok);
tickStream.OnNext(1);
tickStream.OnNext(2);
tickStream.OnNext(3);
statusStream.OnNext(TransientState.Faulted);
tickStream.OnNext(4);
tickStream.OnNext(5);
statusStream.OnNext(TransientState.Ok);
tickStream.OnNext(6);
```

output is `1 2 3 6`, only numbers that came out when state was OK.

Comment: Thank you.  That's certainly something I hadn't considered.